# Doubt regarding converting hex to byte in SHA-256 input

Tags: hash, sha-256, encoding

Hash functions such as SHA-256 takes a binary string as input. Now given a hex string when we convert it to a normal text string the computed SHA-256 value would be the same. Herein lies my problem

Let us consider a simple string in hexadecimals `2E`;
its SHA-256 value is `cdb4ee2aea69cc6a83331bbe96dc2caa9a299d21329efb0336fc02a82e1839a8`.

When converted into byte form should we write `46` or `046`. In either case the SHA-256 output is not matching:

For `46` you'd get
`25fc0e7096fc653718202dc30b0c580b8ab87eac11a700cba03a7c021bc35b0c`.

For `046` you'd get `b2d084ae2bd0f4b38953ea3adb009b4f059816f93392addbcfb373399f183e88`.

How do we convert from hexadecimals to a byte so the result is the same? What are the rules? As far as I know SHA-256 requires byte format.

I've used [this (GitHub)](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) software for calculating the SHA-256 values.

Comment: That site doesn't have a bytes option. How are you entering it as bytes?

Comment: there is a text option in drop down. I assume its bytes?

Comment: The question is about SHA-256, not the different SHA (also known as SHA-0). SHA was a precursor of SHA-1. It turned out to be insecure, even more than SHA-1. The second (resp. third) hash shown is for the two-character (resp. three-character) sequence `46` (resp. `046`) when encoded to as many bytes per ASCII or UTF-8, that is the bytes 0x34 0x36 (resp. 0x30 0x34 0x36) where the 0x prefix is for hexadecimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Let us consider a simple string in Hex: `2E` Its SHA value is:
>
> ```
> cdb4ee2aea69cc6a83331bbe96dc2caa9a299d21329efb0336fc02a82e1839a8
> ```

Yes, that's correct.

> When converted into byte form should we write 46 or 046.

Neither.

The whole idea of using hexadecimals for bytes is to represent the value of the bytes. So `2E` is the hexadecimal representation of a single byte. You can also use other representations such as `00101110` in binary.

If you interpret it as ASCII text it would be the "dot" character. So `printf "\x2E" | sha256sum` is the same as `printf "." | sha256sum` on most systems. So on your site you could simply use a single dot as text. It's also possible to do this using `echo` but `echo` has too many portability issues to be considered a reliable alternative to `printf`.

Generally we don't represent bytes using decimals. If you do you'll probably have to program it specifically. For instance in Java you could use `byte b = 46` or `byte[] ba = { 46 }` and then use that in a hash algorithm. If you really want to program it using command line then `printf "\\x$(printf "%x" 46)" | sha256sum` [seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2747374/589259).

Comment: thank you. But when we initialize the data i.e. w[i]'s before running the Algorithm what do we do as the data required is in bytes by the variables (w[i]'s) being 32 bits)? Do we change the data to binary and then assign or we work directly on Hex by storing them in w[i]'s in hex format. I don't think latter would work and give the correct hash?

Comment: I am trying to write SHA256 from scratch and this part is terribly confusing. The rest of the logic seems fine.. Lets assume the text in Hexa is: 2E 2F 05 EE that is to be populated in W[0]. How do we go about it and what would be its value ?

Comment: Normally we create an interface using bytes for the SHA-256 hash function. In that case the value `2E 2F 05 EE` in bytes would be converted to a single word `0x2E2F05EE` when looking at the SHA-256 implementation. But please note that SHA-256 is defined as using **big** endian. You should **never** use hexadecimals created from a string, only bytes and words. Hexadecimals  are only useful for debugging (the debugger can of course use them, and you can use them in debug print or trace statements), you should **never** use them for the implementation itself.

Comment: You can just *shift the byte value into the right place, using `<<` and then OR them together (beware of snags, lookup on StackOverflow on how to do this when you get stuck). Literals to define the initial values and constants can be defined using hexadecimal bytes or words are fine of course, e.g. `h0 := 0x6a09e667` in the Wikipedia pseudo code is fine, `0x6a09e667` is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

- List item

I used python to bring out the difference,
when you take 2E and just encode as a byte and gives the byte encoded as b'2E'.

- python has a method bytes.fromhex() for ex..
- v=bytes.fromhex('474039')
- here v is printed as  **b'G@9'**
- To decode use binascii.hexlify(v), and output will be ***b'474039'***
  [image]